# How to add class active after AJAX success

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am on try created Navigation Menu using AJAX, my idea add the class `.active` after Menu clicked. And this my code

> HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="default">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content"> Content will be here ... </div>
```

> Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        // if i place addClass here all parent() will have active class
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $.ajax({
            url : page + '.php',
            // if i place removeClass here, no active class show
            beforeSend: function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
            },
            success: function(res) {
                $('#content').html(res);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I need only one `parent()` or `<li>` tag have class active (let we say as current pages after clicking the link. Can somebody tell me, how to achieve this? Many thanks for any suggestions or comments.

Added fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/176903/

Comment: @Dipak chavda, sorry for that.. i make question from mobile phone, hard to make code from mobile phone.

Comment: @it is ok, we all human that is why we moderate question if anything wrong then we may make proper and it will help to understand a question to other people as well.

Comment: Check an answer posted and let us know if not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used dummy ajax request to fulfil the requirement.

> HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

> Javascript

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("#nav li a").on("click", function(e) {
    var activeElement = $(this).parent("li");
    // If your would set active element does not want to complete ajax request then uncomment below and comment ajax request same code
    //$("#nav li").removeClass("active");
    //activeElement.addClass("active");
    $.ajax({
      url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
      success: function(res) {
        // If you would set active element after success of ajax request
        $("#content").html(res);
        $("#nav li").removeClass("active");
        activeElement.addClass("active");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Please review the jsfiddle working example: https://jsfiddle.net/tqbspruv/37/

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Work like a charm.. Thank you @Dipak chavda

Answer (score 0):

I would add the code inside the success callback. Assign an ID to all menu items in the HTML code. Then, in the success callback, remove the active class from all menu items and then add it only to the menu item that was clicked. Maybe something like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    var clickedID = $(this).attr("id");        

    $.ajax({
        url : page + '.php',
        success: function(res) {
            $('ul#nav li a').removeClass('active');
            $("#" + clickedID).addClass('active');
            $('#content').html(res);
        }
    });
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, also works well. But honestly i am not using id for adding active class.. :)